# disable button if there is no image src

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an img tag and a Validate button.

If the img has no src / ng-src the validate button should be disabled.

if there is an image it should be enabled.

the problem is there no ng-model for image, I can't bind the image src to the ng-disabled of the button.

I made a function that returns a bool for the button's ng-disabled attribute.

```
<button ng-disabled="verif($index)" ng-click="...>
<img ng-src={{asset.card_$index}} >
```

```
    $scope.verif = function (index) {
        return !!document.getElementById('im_'+index).src;
    }
```

it should not only work the first time but everytime the src changes.

the image is a base64 data. the img upload  works great, it gets the data from the server or if there is none you have to upload the img by using an input file.

events from input-file are not reliable. i have to check the img src instead

Comment: The function body only needs to be: `return !!document.getElementById('im_'+index).src;`

Comment: if you are not using the ng-model to change the img source, how you change that ?Are you using pure JS dom manipulation code to change. If so you can call $scope.$apply() to rerender.

Comment: @Vishnu ng-model dosen't work with images

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah but that dosen't fix the problem. I made that just to be sure

Comment: I know. That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: How are you assigning `ng-src` on the `<img></img>` element? Can you show us that?

Comment: Think it should be not of verif($index) <button ng-disabled="!verif($index)" ng-click="...>

Comment: @Lex <img ng-src={{asset.card}} > asset.card is base64 data. the img upload  works great, it gets the data from the server or if there is none you have to upload the img by using an input file

Comment: So can't you use `ng-disabled="!asset.card"`?

Comment: @Lex i tried it. it does not work well with the input file. maybe i should make a plunker when i get back home

Answer (score 0):

Check this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/pv3kyt28/2/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}" alt="angular">

    <button type="button" ng-disabled="!img" >Validate</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="clearImg()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="resetImg()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function TestController($scope) {
    var defaultImg = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.seroundtable.com/pic-angular-1431519203.jpg";

    $scope.clearImg = function () {
        $scope.img = '';
    };

    $scope.resetImg = function () {
        $scope.img = angular.copy(defaultImg);
    };


    $scope.resetImg();

}
```

Comment: the ng-src could be from the input file or the server. it would have been easier if it was just a button

Comment: events from input-file are not reliable. i have to check the img src instead

Comment: Does this fulfill your needs ?